# With or without opposition between A and B, how many ways are there for A not to be B?

Tags: logic, metaphysics, reference-request, ontology

I'm looking for references and "loci" regarding the concepts of opposition, distinction, diversity, and negation.

I'm not certain if one must distinguish the case in which A and B stand for concepts or propositions and that which stand for things.

As examples, I can think of the following:

- Plato: Sophist
- Aristotle: On Interpretation
- Aquinas: Summa Theologiae ("In which sense is the Son other than the Father?")
- Micraelius: Lexicon Philosophicum (diversity is a genus having as species opposition and distinction)
- Kant: the distinction between logical opposition and real opposition
- Levinas: the absolute opposition of "the Other".

Comment: I would also add Hegel to the list.  Here’s a book, don’t be put off or be misled by the title, H. Marcuse “Reason and Revolution” https://archive.org/details/reasonandrevolut029499mbp/page/n6  You can see the use of the words “negative” or the negation here, and also not a bad introduction to Hegel and what followed from him in, Left Hegelians, Marx, Frankfurt School etc.

Comment: @Gordon. Thanks for this interesting link. The table of contents is appealing indeed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might enjoy F.H.Bradley's *Appearance and Reality*, in which he analyses and sublates a list of everyday categories and distinctions.

There is also G. S. Brown's *Laws of Form*, in which he presents a formal 'calculus of indications' where an 'indication' is a distinction or category-of-thought.

There is also C.S Peirce, who did a great deal of work on opposites, categories,  distinctions and the like.

In metaphysics it makes no difference whether a distinction is between ideas or objects. They would all be existents subject to the rules of set theory and dialectical logic.